# Car Accident - Can I get Cash/Check instead?

Tags: insurance, car-insurance, reimbursement

My vehicle (pick-up truck) was legally parked on a street and a car struck my truck and caused some damage to the body and bumper. When I called, the other driver's insurance company told me to take it to a collision repair center to get it fixed and give them the estimate and they will pay for it.

My problem is that my truck is a used construction truck with many dents in it, and taking half a day or a full day off of work to drive there and get it fixed is a waste of gas and a waste of my time.

Would it be possible to just have the insurance company send a person to estimate damages and pay me in cash?

Comment: What did they say when you asked them about this? Call them and tell them you'd like and adjuster to come out and appraise the damage and would like a check to cover the repairs. This isn't an uncommon request.

Comment: By the way, I had them come to my workplace and appraise it and they appraised it at $1024, did a background check for IRS because it was over $1000 and then to my surprise, they said that if there are further issues, let them know and they will pay for them as well.

Comment: Quick comment: some car-for-charity programs will accept damaged cars, and you may be able to take whatever price they get for it as a tax deductible donation. I had an accident that left the car in undrivable condition; much to my surprise at auction it went for $3000, savings me $1000 in my taxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can get cash for the accident.   I was in exactly the same scenario and got an insurance payout for a repair I did not want to make.

The risk you are taking is that there is more damage than readily apparent.

For example, if you let the insurance company repair the car, this is a typical scenario:

- Initial estimate is $1000
- Insurance pays $1000
- Take car to get it fixed.  Discover $500 more damage
- Insurance company will now cover that additional $500.

Decide based on the damage and estimates if it's worth taking the risk of having damage missing from the estimate.   In my case it was worth the risk.

Comment: Exactly right. I had a rear-ending recently. Two cars back slammed into the car behind me which scratched my bumper. That car's insurance insisted on sending an adjuster, and they sent me a check. In the old days, we'd look at scratches and walk away. I hit the rock wall pulling out of my garage harder than this, and that's what I told the insurance co. Sent check anyway.

Comment: This happened to me about 20 years ago; a DHL van scraped my (old beater car) door and knocked off my side-view mirror. Took it to a body shop, he sent an estimate to their insurance...next thing I know, $980 check arrives. I kept it, didn't make the repairs, and counted it as a rare windfall.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I inspected the welded body underneath the bumper and it appears solid as a rock.  Already have dents galore from the previous owner.  I'm willing to take the risk.  If anything this can be free money just to deal with the hassle and take a cosmetic hit.

Comment: A friend in college had a beater car parked in the college's off campus party area.  Some young man climbed over his car in full view of a police officer, causing a dent or two on the hood and roof.  That person's insurance sent a check to my friend which went into beer money, rather than repairs